# Artifactory - NuGet - Max Unique Snapshots

Tags: .net, nuget, versioning, artifactory, snapshot

I created nuget local repository on my Artifactory, and set *Max Unique Snapshots* option to 10. However artifactory won't delete old packages.

```
dotnet-snapshots/
├── sompackage/
│   ├── 1.0.0-build1
|   |   ├── somepackage.1.0.0-build1.nupkg
|   ├── 1.0.0-build2
|   |   ├── somepackage.1.0.0-build2.nupkg
│   ├── ...
|   ├── 1.0.0-build25
|   |   ├── somepackage.1.0.0-build25.nupkg
```

Where problem can be ? I think it is something with package naming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be related to the layout used by your repository.
FYI Artifactory is using this layout to extract some metadata such as the base revision, integration revision (snapshots), module name,...

By default a nuget repository uses the "nuget-default" layout defined like this : "[orgPath]/[module]/[module].baseRev.nupkg"

but in your case you are deploying your nuget packages as if the layout were : 
"[orgPath]/[module]/baseRev/[module].baseRev.nupkg"

so what you can do is :

re order you repository to match the layout
OR create a custom layout that match your deployment path

also when you edit/create a layout you can test it with an existing artifacts to chck Artifactory is extracting what you expect from the deployment path.

Comment: Just to add to @jroquelaure reply, as the default Nuget layout in Artifactory is: [orgPath]/[module]/[module].[baseRev](-[fileItegRev]).nupkg
and the '[fileItegRev]' is defined as '.*'
a good file structure for your goal can be:
myProject/somepackage/somepackage.1.0.0-build1.nupkg
This will identify 'build1' as the integration version.
another option might be to create your own layout. perhaps something like:
orgPath]/[module]/[baseRev](-[folderItegRev])/[module].[baseRev](-[fileItegRev]).nupkg
this will match:
myProject/somepackage/1.0.0-build1/somepackage.1.0.0-build1.nupkg